# Is there a way to stop my MacBook Pro from shutting off completely whenever I hit the power button?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, power

I have a mid-2014 13-inch MacBook Pro running Catalina. I have accidentally hit my power button three times in the last three days while trying to hit the backspace key. Whenever I do this, even for a moment, it puts my computer into a state of being technically on but essentially unusable without fully turning it off and on (i.e. I can't use any other keys or the track pad to restore it to full function), which is a hassle and not infrequently leads to lost work.

Is there a way to make it open a dialog box or limit it to only turning off when I hold it down for several seconds or something like that? If not, is there a way of switching the functions of my backspace and right shift keys to make things like this less frequent?

Comment: This might not be useful, but you can create a second user and have it logged in so that when you're in the other account, the Mac asks for an admin password to shut down.

Comment: This is normal behavior - you're [putting your Mac to sleep](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824). Now, it takes a moment to sleep and takes a moment to wake again - it's not instant.  Try tapping the power button again and waiting a few seconds to see if it comes out of sleep/hibernation.  If not, there may be an issue with your sleep image or power settings.  Try that and post the results.

Comment: Also, try this command `defaults write com.apple.loginwindow PowerButtonSleepsSystem -bool no` to force a pop up confirming sleep/shutdown/etc.  Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Allan Tapping the power button again in sleep didn't seem to do anything. Currently trying to use the command.

Comment: @Allan The first time I tried to turn it off with the command, the computer froze and would not unfreeze without me fully turning it off. The second time, it just went to sleep without me being able to wake it up as before.

Comment: Issue the command `pmset -g`. Post the output

Comment: @Allan `System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1`